# discordjs problems logging whenever a dm is sent

Tags: discord.js

I have a whole logging system that logs whenever various things are done in the server or with the bot, one being a log of whenever a dm is sent to the bot. the log would contain the author ID and the message content. the problem is with logging the message content. the bot crashes whenever a second DM is sent but works fine if its a first DM. the bot crash message is the following: https://gyazo.com/5ad0b41648f83a855ac8c49fb220a612

but the strange thing is, my fields aren't empty:

```js
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    const LogChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('712811824826941460');
    const LogEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#606060')
    .setAuthor(msg.author.tag)
    .setDescription('DM Sent')
    .addField('Message', msg.content)
    .setTimestamp()
    if(msg.channel.type === 'dm')
    LogChannel.send(LogEmbed)
});
```

the console thinks that the `.addField('Message', msg.content)` is empty but as you can see, it's not. keep in mind it only gives me the error message after a second DM is sent following a first one.
any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't send images of code/errors or even link them to pastebin or gyazo, copy and paste them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Message.content` properties. I guess you are looking for [`Message.cleanContent`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=cleanContent)

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    const LogChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('712811824826941460');
    const LogEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#606060')
    .setAuthor(msg.author.tag)
    .setDescription('DM Sent')
    .addField('Message', msg.cleanContent)
    .setTimestamp()
    if(msg.channel.type === 'dm')
    LogChannel.send(LogEmbed)
});
```

Comment: it still crashes after a second message is sent

Comment: same as before, https://gyazo.com/5ad0b41648f83a855ac8c49fb220a612

Comment: Have you tried to log all the variables you are inclusing in the embed to see their values ?

Comment: Simply use `console.log(msg.author.tag)` or the other variables / properties and check the console to see if the variables are corectly set